# HTTP error (406): Ruby on Rails and Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, savon, http-status-code-406

Well I'm using Savon to consume a wash_out SOAP server.

Everything seems all right because I can send my SOAP messages and the server can save them into a mysql database.

My problem comes after my client send the request because I'm receiving an HTTP error (406):   coming from the request that looks like this:

```
response = client.call(:crear_articulo) do
  message texto: ":3", titulo: ":'("
end
```

In the server I have the following code:
    soap_action "crear_articulo",
              :args   => { :texto => :string, :titulo => :string },
              :return => :string

And the method that is handling the request is like this:

```
def crear_articulo
  @ar = Articulo.new
  @ar.titulo = params[:titulo]
  @ar.texto = params[:texto]
  if @ar.save
    render :soap => "Correcto"
  else
    render :soap => "Error"
  end
end
```

I guess the error is in the server but, I can't see where it is. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can read parameters from a soap request directly from the `params` variable?

Comment: I think I can because as I mention, the logic is working because my database is being filled.

And this is an example from the wash_out documentation:

    def concat
     render :soap => (params[:a] + params[:b])
    end

Comment: cool gem.  i'd suspect the client, because 406 means that the client won't accept the `application/soap+xml` MIME type

Comment: Any suggestion about how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/master/lib/savon/request.rb seems to suggest that you'll need to set `@globals[:soap_version] = 2`